# My position generation method doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method that is supposed to generate a certain number of Vector3 at a distance not less than specified.

```
   // Generate random point based on plane area
    public List<Vector3> GeneratePositions(int numberOfPositions, float minDistanceBetweenPositions)
    {
        float entireArea = 0f;
        List<AreasWeight> areasWeights = new List<AreasWeight>();
        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();

        foreach (GeneratorPlane plane in GeneratorPlanes.GetCollectionAsList())
        {
            entireArea += plane.GetArea();
        }
        foreach (GeneratorPlane plane in GeneratorPlanes.GetCollectionAsList())
        {
            float weight = plane.GetArea() / entireArea;
            int numOfPositionsInArea = Mathf.RoundToInt(numberOfPositions * weight);
            areasWeights.Add(new(plane, weight, numOfPositionsInArea));
        }

        foreach (AreasWeight areaWeight in areasWeights)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < areaWeight.NumOfPointsInArea; i++)
            {
                Vector3 generatedPoint = areaWeight.Plane.GetRandomPointOnPlane();

                foreach (Vector3 position in positions)
                {
                    int attempts = 1;

                    while ((position - generatedPoint).magnitude < minDistanceBetweenPositions)
                    {
                        generatedPoint = areaWeight.Plane.GetRandomPointOnPlane();
                        attempts++;

                        if (attempts > 2000)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Can't generate all positions.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                positions.Add(generatedPoint);
            }
        }

        return positions;
    }
```

Get random point method:

```
 public Vector3 GetRandomPointOnPlane()
    {
        float xPosition = Random.Range(Mathf.Min(DownPoint.x, DownPointHelper.x), Mathf.Max(DownPoint.x, DownPointHelper.x));
        float zPosition = Random.Range(Mathf.Min(DownPoint.z, UpPointHelper.z), Mathf.Max(DownPoint.z, UpPointHelper.z));

        return new(xPosition, DownPoint.y + 0.002f, zPosition);
    }
```

But when i Instantiate objects based on these Vector3. Objects still have a distance less than the specified. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Would you elaborate on the `DownPoint`, `DownPointHelper` and `UpPointHelper`? how do you get those values, and shouldn't you have a `UpPoint` too?

Comment: Do you get `Can't generate all positions.` logs? because if you "can't generate the position" you still add it to `positions`

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer I get this log only when I enter some huge value. With normal (for example, 2), the method is performed without log. And these points are set using the custom editor and the OnGizmos unity method. These points work as they should. The field also comes out correct. Objects are instanced, but do not maintain a distance between each other

Comment: as general notes depending on how expensive they are you might want to cache things like `GeneratorPlanes.GetCollectionAsList()` and `plane.GetArea()` ... This might also be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463266/algorithm-for-distributing-points-evenly-but-randomly-in-a-rectangle or go even one level higher https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15624/distribute-a-fixed-number-of-points-uniformly-inside-a-polygon/

Comment: @derHugo Actually, the method is only supposed to be called when the scene is loading, so I don't care much about it not being expensive

Answer (score 0):

On the original code if you generate a point 2000 times you actually keep the last `generatedPoint`, and as you mentioned you don't actually cross check the whole list of positions, only the remaining positions.

Although you have solved your problem and posted a solution, I took the liberty of doing a simple script with the same end, I will share it here in hopes its useful for you or others.

This solution will not fill any area, its only making sure no two objects are at shorter distance than specified.

In my tests, with 50 `nPoints` only 10/20 points are instantiated before a point takes over 2000 attempts and consequently conclude the search for points. Although this will depend on the ratio between `spawnLimits` and `nPoints`.

```cs
[SerializeField]
GameObject trunkPrefab;

List<Vector3> positions;

//input variables
int nPoints = 50;
float minDistance = 2.5f;
int spawnLimits = 20;

void Start()
{
    positions = new();

    for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
    {
        Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;
        bool newPosition = true;
        int attempts = 0;
        do
        {
            //first generation will be automatically added to the list
            position = new(Random.Range(-spawnLimits, spawnLimits), .5f, Random.Range(-spawnLimits, spawnLimits));
            if (positions.Count < 1)
            {
                break;
            }

            //every position will be compared here,
            //if any position is too close from then new position
            //"newPosition" is set to false and we try again from the start.
            for (int p = 0; p < positions.Count; p++)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(position, positions[p]) < minDistance)
                {
                    newPosition = false;

                    attempts++;
                    if (attempts > 2000)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Max attempts reached.");
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!newPosition);

        //adding a random rotation
        Vector3 rotation = new(Random.Range(80, 100), Random.Range(0, 179), 0);

        Instantiate(trunkPrefab, position, Quaternion.Euler(rotation));
        positions.Add(position);
    }
}
```

[image: Output example]

Comment: I checked and the "GetRandomPointOnPlane" method returns the correct result. The while loop is also performed sometimes. But I don't understand why sometimes it doesn't work. It looks as if the foreach loop iterating through the list of positions does not execute on every position it contains.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of the results you mention? both the points with the gismos, and the instance of the objects? also add a snippet of the instance code just in case.

Comment: I am posting here the links to the results ![Before](https://ibb.co/Mktjzm2) ![After](https://ibb.co/6bStFzk) ![Logs](https://ibb.co/NF3T5q1). And Instantiate method:                                                                                                       ```
public void SpawnTrash()
{
    Debug.Log("Started spawning");
    List<Vector3> points = _trashGenerator.GeneratePositions(_numberOfTrash, _distanceBetweenTrash);
    foreach (Vector3 point in points)
    {
        Instantiate(_trashPrefab, point, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. The while function checks the distance between the generated point and the current foreach point. But if we are at the 50th point in the list and the distance is too small, the GetrandomPosOnPlane() function will generate a point that has the distance preserved. But this point can be generated close to previous points in the list because the algorithm doesn't check them afterwards. I don't know if I explained it clearly.

Comment: I've added my own solution and explanation if you're interested

Comment: Its great that you manage to solve it, I edited my answer to briefly mention some issues on your original code and provide a clean solution to the problem at hand.

For posterity try to keep you question as clean as possible, with all relevant information detailed, I actually missed at first the obvious issue on your code but took me a while to read and understand the whole code, if it would be resumed maybe the issue could be spotted more easily, and have more answers. 

Better question better answer, try this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was a bad loop structure. When the algorithm confirmed that the distance was too small and generated a new one, it did not check whether the generated position had a gap from the previous positions on the list. It only confirmed that the gap was preserved and the program continued to execute.

I moved the code that makes sure that the distances are saved to the `public List<Vector3> GeneratePositions(int numberOfPositions, float minDistanceBetweenPositions)` method in the GeneratorPlane class. I also added a `private Vector3 PickRandomPos()` method to it, just to return the generated position.

Methods in the `public class GeneratorPlane`:

```csharp
public Vector3 GetRandomPointOnPlane(List<Vector3> alreadyGeneratedPoints, float minDistnaceBetweenPositions)
    {
        if (alreadyGeneratedPoints.Count != 0)
        {
            int attemps = 1;
            bool pointFound = false;
            Vector3 posToReturn = new();

            while (!pointFound)
            {
                pointFound = true;
                posToReturn = PickRandomPos();
                foreach (Vector3 position in alreadyGeneratedPoints)
                {
                    if (Vector3.Distance(position, posToReturn) < minDistnaceBetweenPositions)
                    {
                        pointFound = false;
                        attemps++;
                        if (attemps > 2000)
                        {
                            Debug.LogError("Points cannot be generated. Too little available space");
                            return Vector3.zero;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return posToReturn;
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("First point generated");
            return PickRandomPos();
        }
    }

    private Vector3 PickRandomPos()
    {
        float xPosition = Random.Range(Mathf.Min(DownPoint.x, DownPointHelper.x), Mathf.Max(DownPoint.x, DownPointHelper.x));
        float zPosition = Random.Range(Mathf.Min(DownPoint.z, UpPointHelper.z), Mathf.Max(DownPoint.z, UpPointHelper.z));

        return new(xPosition, DownPoint.y + 0.002f, zPosition);
    }
```

Method to generate and return a certain number of items:

```csharp
public List<Vector3> GeneratePositions(int numberOfPositions, float minDistanceBetweenPositions)
    {
        float entireArea = 0f;
        List<AreasWeight> areasWeights = new();
        List<Vector3> positions = new();

        foreach (GeneratorPlane plane in PlanesGenerator.GetCollectionAsList())
        {
            entireArea += plane.GetArea();
        }

        foreach (GeneratorPlane plane in PlanesGenerator.GetCollectionAsList())
        {
            float weight = plane.GetArea() / entireArea;
            int numOfPositionsInArea = Mathf.RoundToInt(numberOfPositions * weight);
            areasWeights.Add(new(plane, weight, numOfPositionsInArea));
        }

        foreach (AreasWeight areaWeight in areasWeights)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < areaWeight.NumOfPointsInArea; i++)
            {
                Vector3 generatedPoint = areaWeight.Plane.GetRandomPointOnPlane(positions, minDistanceBetweenPositions);
                positions.Add(generatedPoint);
            }
        }

        return positions;
    }
```